# Filter on json data with in_() sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to filter features(Json field on database) with items = a or b, but here it returns 0, when I use other columns the filter works correctly. It returns correct data with ["a"] or ["b"] too, what is the reason? and what is the solution?

```
data.filter(Data.id.in_([1,2])) #works

data.filter(Data.features['items'].in_(["a"])) # returns 3

data.filter(Data.features['items'].in_(["b"])) # returns 1

data.filter(Data.features['items'].in_(["a","b"])) # returns 0 I exepect 4
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate and add sample data and the expected results to the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.filter(Data.features['items'].in_(["a","b"]))` returns 0 because `data.filter()` is looking features with both `a` and `b` in the items field.

if you only want either `a` *or* `b`, you'll need to filter with an `or_` operator from sqlalchemy import:

```
data.filter(or_(Data.features['items'].in_(["a"]), Data.features['items'].in_(["b"])))
```

Comment: Thank you this was the thing that I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing here, but you might be looking to use `contains` instead of `in_`.

Please try the below queries instead:

```py
q = select(Data).filter(Data.features['items'].contains("a"))
q = select(Data).filter(Data.features['items'].contains("b"))
q = select(Data).filter(or_(  # i assume it is OR, but you might have wanted AND instead
    Data.features['items'].contains("a"), 
    Data.features['items'].contains("b"),
))
```